# Does Facebook provide a way of showing their login page while a user is logged in to facebook.com?

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-login

Sorry to ask this but browsing the Facebook documentation I cannot find a clue for that.

Does Facebook provide a way of showing their login page with a username textbox while a user is logged in to facebook.com?
So the user would be able to choose another account.

**Edit**

The functionality I'd like to add to a site/app - is to enable users to choose from different Facebook accounts.

Thanks
Ilan

Comment: You want to be able to access Facebook via two accounts simultaneously on Facebook site itself???Or want to build an application that will allow users to choose from different Facebook accounts??

Comment: @WorldGamer Thanks I've edited the question so it should be clearer. The second option is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Ok m not very sure,but lets think it like this,when a person registers to your site using Facebook,the site stores his email address and authenticate that email address using Facebook.
Now when you allow a user to register them self using Facebook,you may do it like this:
Ask user to enter the email address first,and then try to authenticate to Facebook using that email address.This way user will get a chance to choose his preferred Facebook account.Note if you directly use the facebook connect button ,it will login in you with the open facebook account.so use the email address to authenticate .